# How to classify a frequency domain data in Python 3? (could not convert string to float)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've converted a DataFrame from time domain to frequency domain using :

```
df = np.fft.fft(df)
```

Now I need to classify the the data using several machine learning algorithms such as Random Forest and Gaussian Naive Bayes. The problem is I keep getting this error:

> could not convert string to float: '`(2.9510193818016135-0.47803712350473193j)`'

I tried to convert the strings to floats in `DataFrame` but it is still giving me the same error.

How can I solve this problem in order to get my classification results?

Comment: Those are complex numbers, how do you propose to convert to float? Basically you need to convert these numbers to either polar or rect format and split them

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your results are like the following form, you first need to cast to a real complex type:

```
In[84]:
# data setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'fft':['(2.9510193818016135-0.47803712350473193j)']})
df

Out[84]: 
                                         fft
0  (2.9510193818016135-0.47803712350473193j)
```

Now cast to `complex` type:

```
In[85]:

df['complex'] = df['fft'].apply(complex)
df

Out[85]: 
                                         fft                         complex
0  (2.9510193818016135-0.47803712350473193j)  (2.9510193818-0.478037123505j)
```

Now you can extract as polar coords using `apply` with `cmath.polar`:

```
In[86]:
import cmath
df['polar_x'],df['polar_y'] = df['complex'].apply(lambda x: cmath.polar(x)[0]), df['complex'].apply(lambda x: cmath.polar(x)[1])
df

Out[86]: 
                                         fft                         complex  \
0  (2.9510193818016135-0.47803712350473193j)  (2.9510193818-0.478037123505j)   

    polar_x   polar_y  
0  2.989487 -0.160595
```

Now the `dtypes` are compatible so you can pass the float columns:

```
In[87]:
df.dtypes

Out[87]: 
fft            object
complex    complex128
polar_x       float64
polar_y       float64
dtype: object
```

You can also use [`cmath.rect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) if desired

Comment: Why i get KeyError for 'fft' and 'complex' ?

Comment: Because your df is a numpy array, in my example I have a pandas dataframe so you need to modify your code

Comment: no it is pandas dataframe i even used ( df  = pd.DataFrame(df) ) to ensure it is a dataframe

Comment: so do you have those columns? I knocked up an illustrative example, I have no idea what your real df looks like, for instance what does `df.columns.tolist()` return?

Comment: so do you have those columns? I knocked up an illustrative example, I have no idea what your real df looks like, for instance what does `df.columns.tolist()` return? The point here is that you use whatever column names you have or you construct a df with those column names this is something you can look up

Comment: i want to convert the whole dataframe. why you used this complex number:  2.9510193818016135-0.47803712350473193j. it was the first element in dataframe that is why it appeared in the error message.

Comment: Look I can only answer what is put in front of me, you posted a code snippet with no raw data, no code to reproduce your actual df, just an error message. I posted an answer that showed how to deal with complex numbers, beyond that this becomes a crystal ball gazing exercise because you're telling me the symptoms without providing any data or code that I can use to reproduce any errors

Comment: my original data are 3000 rows and 20000 columns all are float type. i converted the data into frequency domain which resulted in 3000 rows and 20000 columns in complex type. i need to convert the data to floats to classify it that is all.

Comment: Then you need to use my code to do the conversion, it's still not clear what you really expect with that many columns as you need to convert the components to float form and then `fit` on the split components. IMO I'd split each of the columns into separate dfs and perform the dtype conversion and fit and then merge back but that is beyond the scope of this question